# Как нужно после считывания qr кода закрывать ресурсы и открывать стартовую\родительскую активность?

Tags: java, android, json, qr

Проблема в том, что при таком подходе в методе `jsonPost(qrData)` идёт несколько запросов к серверу, а нужен только один.

```
   @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> qrcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (qrcodes.size() != 0) {
                txtResult.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        txtResult.setText(qrcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                        qrData = qrcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                        String text = jsonPost(qrData);
                        Log.d("Text", text);
                        if (text.contains("success")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Операція успішна", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            cameraSource.release();
                            cameraSource.stop();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MinusBonusesActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

}


public String jsonPost(String qrData) {
    String url = "http://admin.bonsitecrm.com/api/customer/add_bonus_manager";
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                    responseFromServer = response;
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("json", "{ \"user_id\":\"216\", \"customer_id\":\"6664\", \"operation\":\"minus\", \"amount\":\"100\", \"subject\":\"Тест\", \"access_token\":\"VHvjY3TFsSrDlbCg2MaeHInvyRGqQchMUN5SQZyjRZWdbytelEs3mPyUHelyrCklpqegpMAhMwuX5YbrCEvYu3TbheKIR43huiyU58bRFGPLE1dgGIfaL9m2o6LgbPxF\" }");
            Log.d("Map", params.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(postRequest);
    Log.d("ResponseFromServer", responseFromServer);
    return responseFromServer;
}
```

Вывод консоли:

```
    01-11 16:18:37.877 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses                                                                 
    D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
    01-11 16:18:38.128 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Camera: app passed NULL surface
    01-11 16:18:38.334 26887-27087/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses 
    D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7fa0ba2800 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f8cf40e20
    01-11 16:18:38.850 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses I/Timeline: 
    Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:623583262
    01-11 16:18:38.929 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses 
    W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
    01-11 16:18:38.935 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses 
    I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1402
    01-11 16:18:38.935 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses 
    I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1402
    01-11 16:18:38.955 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses I/Vision: Loading library libbarhopper.so
    01-11 16:18:38.956 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses I/Vision: libbarhopper.so library load status: true
    01-11 16:18:38.978 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses 
    D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
    01-11 16:18:39.977 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses I/Choreographer: Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    01-11 16:18:42.531 26887-3531/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Map: {json={ "user_id":"216", "customer_id":"6664", "operation":"minus", "amount":"100", "subject":"Тест", "access_token":"VHvjY3TFsSrDlbCg2MaeHInvyRGqQchMUN5SQZyjRZWdbytelEs3mPyUHelyrCklpqegpMAhMwuX5YbrCEvYu3TbheKIR43huiyU58bRFGPLE1dgGIfaL9m2o6LgbPxF" }}
    01-11 16:18:42.720 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Response: {"status":"success","code":"0","message":"success"}
    01-11 16:18:42.722 26887-3534/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Map: {json={ "user_id":"216", "customer_id":"6664", "operation":"minus", "amount":"100", "subject":"Тест", "access_token":"VHvjY3TFsSrDlbCg2MaeHInvyRGqQchMUN5SQZyjRZWdbytelEs3mPyUHelyrCklpqegpMAhMwuX5YbrCEvYu3TbheKIR43huiyU58bRFGPLE1dgGIfaL9m2o6LgbPxF" }}
    01-11 16:18:42.722 26887-3531/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Map: {json={ "user_id":"216", "customer_id":"6664", "operation":"minus", "amount":"100", "subject":"Тест", "access_token":"VHvjY3TFsSrDlbCg2MaeHInvyRGqQchMUN5SQZyjRZWdbytelEs3mPyUHelyrCklpqegpMAhMwuX5YbrCEvYu3TbheKIR43huiyU58bRFGPLE1dgGIfaL9m2o6LgbPxF" }}
    01-11 16:18:42.722 26887-3532/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Map: {json={ "user_id":"216", "customer_id":"6664", "operation":"minus", "amount":"100", "subject":"Тест", "access_token":"VHvjY3TFsSrDlbCg2MaeHInvyRGqQchMUN5SQZyjRZWdbytelEs3mPyUHelyrCklpqegpMAhMwuX5YbrCEvYu3TbheKIR43huiyU58bRFGPLE1dgGIfaL9m2o6LgbPxF" }}
    01-11 16:18:42.731 26887-3533/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Map: {json={ "user_id":"216", "customer_id":"6664", "operation":"minus", "amount":"100", "subject":"Тест", "access_token":"VHvjY3TFsSrDlbCg2MaeHInvyRGqQchMUN5SQZyjRZWdbytelEs3mPyUHelyrCklpqegpMAhMwuX5YbrCEvYu3TbheKIR43huiyU58bRFGPLE1dgGIfaL9m2o6LgbPxF" }}
    01-11 16:18:42.738 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/ResponseFromServer: {"status":"success","code":"0","message":"success"}
    01-11 16:18:42.738 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Text: {"status":"success","code":"0","message":"success"}
    01-11 16:18:42.789 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Camera: app passed NULL surface
    01-11 16:18:42.816 26887-3531/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Map: {json={ "user_id":"216", "customer_id":"6664", "operation":"minus", "amount":"100", "subject":"Тест", "access_token":"VHvjY3TFsSrDlbCg2MaeHInvyRGqQchMUN5SQZyjRZWdbytelEs3mPyUHelyrCklpqegpMAhMwuX5YbrCEvYu3TbheKIR43huiyU58bRFGPLE1dgGIfaL9m2o6LgbPxF" }}
    01-11 16:18:42.865 26887-3533/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Map: {json={ "user_id":"216", "customer_id":"6664", "operation":"minus", "amount":"100", "subject":"Тест", "access_token":"VHvjY3TFsSrDlbCg2MaeHInvyRGqQchMUN5SQZyjRZWdbytelEs3mPyUHelyrCklpqegpMAhMwuX5YbrCEvYu3TbheKIR43huiyU58bRFGPLE1dgGIfaL9m2o6LgbPxF" }}
    01-11 16:18:42.868 26887-3532/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Map: {json={ "user_id":"216", "customer_id":"6664", "operation":"minus", "amount":"100", "subject":"Тест", "access_token":"VHvjY3TFsSrDlbCg2MaeHInvyRGqQchMUN5SQZyjRZWdbytelEs3mPyUHelyrCklpqegpMAhMwuX5YbrCEvYu3TbheKIR43huiyU58bRFGPLE1dgGIfaL9m2o6LgbPxF" }}
    01-11 16:18:42.949 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses I/Timeline: 
    Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:623587362
    01-11 16:18:42.986 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Response: {"status":"success","code":"0","message":"success"}
    01-11 16:18:42.987 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Response: {"status":"success","code":"0","message":"success"}
    01-11 16:18:42.987 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Response: {"status":"success","code":"0","message":"success"}
    01-11 16:18:42.987 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Response: {"status":"success","code":"0","message":"success"}
    01-11 16:18:42.987 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Response: {"status":"success","code":"0","message":"success"}
    01-11 16:18:42.998 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Response: {"status":"success","code":"0","message":"success"}
    01-11 16:18:42.998 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses D/Response: {"status":"success","code":"0","message":"success"}
    01-11 16:18:43.041 26887-26887/com.work.golinko.shkafbonuses 
    D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
```

Comment: Хотя бы отфильтровали бы логи.

Comment: У меня сомнения, что метод вызывается несколько раз, так как сканер читает постоянно и, при любом успешном прочтении, он вызывает ваш метод. Необходимо больше информации и кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить эту проблему добавив флаг для отключения qr ридера во время отправки запроса на сервер

```
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> qrcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (qrcodes.size() != 0) {
                //this "isRun"  will help us to stop qr reader during post request
                if (!isRun) {
                    txtResult.post(QRTask = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            isRun = true;
                            qrData = qrcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            jsonPost(qrData);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

А также изменив параметры по умолчанию в библиотеке Volley, так как она ждала 2,5с ответа от сервера и если не дожидалась, то отправляла запрос повторно.

```
 // here we change RetryPolicy because by default Volley will wait for 2.5 seconds and then sends new request
    postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(postRequest);
```

Вот ссылка на весь проект- https://github.com/Chumva/QR_Bonuses/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/work/golinko/shkafbonuses/AddBonusesActivity.java